# PHP / cURL - Redirect and remain where the function was

Tags: php, redirect, curl

I use this code/script:

```
<?php

//Upload a blank cookie.txt to the same directory as this file with a CHMOD/Permission to 777
function login($url,$data){
    $fp = fopen("cookie.txt", "w");
    fclose($fp);
    $login = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec ($login);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($login);
    unset($login);    
}                  

function grab_page($site){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Expect:"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec ($ch);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($ch);
}

function post_data($site,$data,$data){
    $datapost = curl_init();
        $headers = array("Expect:");
     curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
         curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
         curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
         curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
     curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
     curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
     curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
         curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec ($datapost);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($datapost);
    unset($datapost);   

}

?>
```

This script run in my vps on the another website and complete automatic some functions. I want after execute the function to redirect the original website where he remained on my vps.

example: my code/script work like google.com/page1 execute the function automatic to the page4 and when i use the redirect he start again to google.com/page1 and i want to remaining page4 when i redirect.

Is posibile the original website have auto refresh or something?

Sorry for bad english.

Comment: Do you always shout?

Comment: what? i cant understand what you say?

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl_getinfo().

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

```
echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Expect:"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
    ob_start();
    curl_exec ($ch);
$last_redirected_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($ch);

echo $last_redirected_url;
```

Comment: example please? echo curl_getinfo($ch, http://google.com); just this? i dont need anything else?

Comment: thanks for script but im newbie in php curl.. i know how to use if i have full exemple.. please? i mean where i need add my website in this script? or where i need to replace?

Comment: your code is only functions not main script so I can't help you about this.